# Read binary file as string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, file-io

I need an easy way to take a tar file and convert it into a string (and vice versa). Is there a way to do this in Ruby? My best attempt was this:

```
file = File.open("path-to-file.tar.gz")
contents = ""
file.each {|line|
  contents << line
}
```

I thought that would be enough to convert it to a string, but then when I try to write it back out like this...

```
newFile = File.open("test.tar.gz", "w")
newFile.write(contents)
```

It isn't the same file. Doing `ls -l` shows the files are of different sizes, although they are pretty close (and opening the file reveals most of the contents intact). Is there a small mistake I'm making or an entirely different (but workable) way to accomplish this?

Comment: That's a gzipped tar file (I hope). There are no "lines". Pls clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: are you trying to look at the compressed data or uncompressed content?

Comment: so chars in a compressed data stream will have roughly 1 in 256 chance of landing on "\n" defining end of a line, and that's ok if it doesn't expect "\r" too, see my answer below

Comment: This question should be re-titled as "Convert *binary* file to string", since `IO.read` would be the preferred answer otherwise.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

First, you should open the file as a binary file. Then you can read the entire file in, in one command.

```
file = File.open("path-to-file.tar.gz", "rb")
contents = file.read
```

That will get you the entire file in a string.

After that, you probably want to `file.close`. If you don’t do that, `file` won’t be closed until it is garbage-collected, so it would be a slight waste of system resources while it is open.

Comment: The binary flag is only relevant on Windows, and this leaves the file descriptor open. File.read(...) is better.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with so many people looking this up and copy pasting it as a one-liner solution (like so many things on stackoverflow)? After all, it works, and the name for these functions were just an arbitrary choice of the ruby library designers. If only we had some language with synonyms... that still somehow knows exactly what we want in edge cases/ambiguous instances. Then I would just `contents = (contents of file "path to file.txt" as string)`.

Comment: This should be done in `begin {..open..} ensure {..close..} end` blocks

Comment: @Nobu If the file is malicious, could opening it up as a binary cause problems?

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh No, it's another method of reading the file -- it doesn't mean that it will be treated as an exectuable and run!  That would be a horrifying side-effect for a simple 'read' method.

Comment: The best one-liner (that does not leave the file descriptor open) IMHO would be `contents = File.open('path-to-file.tar.gz', 'rb', &:read)`

Comment: @David couldn't you simply do the following one-liner? `contents = File.binread('path-to-file.tar.gz')` See [apidock](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/IO/binread/class).  `File` is a subclass of `IO`.

Answer (score 249):

If you need binary mode, you'll need to do it the hard way:

```
s = File.open(filename, 'rb') { |f| f.read }
```

If not, shorter and sweeter is:

```
s = IO.read(filename)
```

Comment: In ruby 1.9.3+, IO.read will give you a string marked with the encoding in Encoding.default_external.  I _think_ (?) the bytes will all be as they were in the file, so it's not exactly "not binary-safe", but you'll have to tag it with the binary encoding if that's what you want.

Comment: If shortness and sweetness is of the essence, the ampersand-symbol proc trick gives `s = File.open(filename, 'rb', &:read)`

Answer (score 116):

To avoid leaving the file open, it is best to pass a block to File.open.  This way, the file will be closed after the block executes.

```
contents = File.open('path-to-file.tar.gz', 'rb') { |f| f.read }
```

Comment: This is a better answer than David Nehme's because file descriptors are a finite system resource and exhausting them is a common problem that can easily be avoided.

Answer (score 20):

Ruby have binary reading

```
data = IO.binread(path/filaname)
```

or if less than  Ruby 1.9.2

```
data = IO.read(path/file)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Ruby 1.9.2+.

Answer (score 17):

how about some open/close safety.

```
string = File.open('file.txt', 'rb') { |file| file.read }
```

Comment: why not an explicit .close? Such as in the OP file.close when done?

Comment: File.open() {|file| block} automatically closes when the block terminates.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: This is identical to [Aaron Hinni's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/131096/215168) that was posted in 2008 (except not using OP's file and variable names)...

Answer (score 16):

on os x these are the same for me... could this maybe be extra "\r" in windows?

in any case you may be better of with:

```
contents = File.read("e.tgz")
newFile = File.open("ee.tgz", "w")
newFile.write(contents)
```

Comment: This seems like the most simple solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can probably encode the tar file in Base64. Base 64 will give you a pure ASCII representation of the file that you can store in a plain text file. Then you can retrieve the tar file by decoding the text back.

You do something like:

```
require 'base64'

file_contents = Base64.encode64(tar_file_data)
```

Have look at the Base64 [Rubydocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/index.html) to get a better idea.

Comment: Great, this looks like it'll work too! I'll have to check it out if for some reason reading the binary contents goes sour.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 1.9+ has [`IO.binread`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-binread) (see [@bardzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799222/27358)) and also supports passing the encoding as an option to `IO.read`:

- [Ruby 1.9](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-read)

  ```rb
  data = File.read(name, {:encoding => 'BINARY'})
  ```
- [Ruby 2+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read)

  ```rb
  data = File.read(name, encoding: 'BINARY')
  ```

(Note in both cases that `'BINARY'` is an [alias](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Encoding.html#method-c-aliases) for `'ASCII-8BIT'`.)

Answer (score -2):

If you can encode the tar file by Base64 (and storing it in a plain text file) you can use

```
File.open("my_tar.txt").each {|line| puts line}
```

**or**

```
File.new("name_file.txt", "r").each {|line| puts line}
```

to print each (text) line in the cmd.