# Chef Cookbook that starts with a small powershell script, need to pass the returned integer value to Chef

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to finish someone's cookbook, and I need to be able to have Chef pick up the returned integer of 0 from this script (Some details have been removed) Any suggestions on what might work here in Chef? I've already added the Powershell module in Chef, and specifically I'm asking about the order of what Chef would parse this data in - as in the action: item to hand this variable to... Thanks.

```
include_recipe "chef_handler

powershell_script do
  code <<-EOH
  ###############
  # 
  # Description:
  # Returns 1 if any share or share path allow read/write by the 'Everyone' group (fail)
  # Returns 0 if this condition is not found (pass)


  Try
  {
    #get all shares
    $shares = e | Select-Object Name,Path
    if($shares)
    {
      Foreach ($share in $shares)
      {
        #check everyone permissions
        $shareAccounts = -Name $share.Name
        Foreach ($account in $shareAccounts)
        {
          If ($account.AName -eq 'Everyone')
          {
            return 1
          }
        }

        #check 
        $volumePerm = Get-ACL $share.Path
        if ($volume.Access.Where({$Reference -eq 'Everyone'}))
        {
          return 1
        }
      }
    }
    else
    return 0


    #loop through each share checking for 'Everyone'
    # pass the return values send to Chef or something else.
  }

  {
    #build error message
  }
  Finally
  {
    #return final message
  }
  EOH

  fail "Instance has failed the OpenShares check" if code == 1

end
```

Comment: The workaround we used is to write it to a tmp file, read it back from Chef and delete it.

Comment: Thanks Wai Yan, do you have a snippet you are able to share? I hadn't thought of that.    :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef resources don't have output values. If the PowerShell script fails, it will abort the Chef run, otherwise it will proceed.

Comment: Thanks coderanger, that confirmed the reason it was failing. Which is why I prefer to start with my own messes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the `returns` parameter of `powershell_script` block. If you specify a value like `[0,1]`, the script will not fail. You can also not specify anything and try to catch the exception using Ruby `rescue`.

That said, if you really need the value, my suggestion is to write the value to a file and read it back at the end of the process, instead of returning it.

You can refer to this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/0a6860f5-9b02-4e79-97fe-05829f2c5ab3/open-write-and-close-the-file-using-powershell?forum=ITCG) for writing stuff to file using powershell and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130948/ruby-convert-file-to-string) for reading the file to `String` in Ruby.

Comment: Interesting, many thanks Wai Yan, very appreciated. At the start, the word code creates a variable that will contain whatever is returned. It's not defined to be a certain type. So I will look at both of those links carefully, I think ruby catch may be the one I'm most interested in. Too soon to tell. However you have opened my eyes to some different possibilities. Now I need to better understand how to use rescue in the code before I can make that decision. I'm already late with this so I will just do what must be done. Thanks - I'll post an update provided I can figure that out.:-)